# RoR: undefined method new for #<Class>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, resources, nested

I am dealing with the nested resource in Rails. My User has one Farm.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_one :farm

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable


attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username

end
```

Farm controller

```
 class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user

 attr_accessible :name, :contact, :adress, :user_id
 end
```

My Farm migration

```
class CreateFarms < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :farms do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.string :name
  t.string :contact
  t.string :adress

  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

My routes.rb

```
 resources :users do
  resource :farm, path: "farm"
 end


 devise_for :users, :path => 'account
```

So I am thinking all of my references and associations are ok. But when I try to make a new Farm, I get the said error. My new method in FarmsController:

```
def new

@farm = @user.farm.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @farm }
end
end
```

I also have the load_User function that is set to before_filter

```
def load_User
  @user = User.find(current_user)

end
```

Same thing happens for my show function where i use

```
@farm = @user.farm.find(params[:id])
```

It says no method "find". 
I cannot guess or find why this is, if someone can help and/or elaborate..

Comment: I just added that it does same for "find" method.

Comment: You should consider removing these `attr_accessible` in your User model (and probably Farm aswell), because its misleading a little.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Your answer cleared a lot of other related stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this error because (probably) you try to call `find` on `Farm` instance, which doesn't have `find` method defined. Since `@user.farm` already returns `Farm` instance (or `nil`), you should have simply:

```
@farm = @user.farm
```

Your first error is similar. It occurs because there's not `new` method defined for `Farm` instance. Instead, you should have:

```
@farm = @user.build_farm
```

Answer (score 5):

1. There is no `@user.farm.new` method, because its one-to-one association. Try `@user.build_farm`
2. Its really simple. If there is only one farm, then there is no need to search for it. `@user.farm` should be enough.